# Webpage loading fine - Getting 404 error in Chrome! Internal broken links galore

Tags: java, jquery, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have looked over other peoples posts but I cant find anything to fix this specific error.

On my site, I have 2 CMS - one for the main site which is OS Commerce and I 
have Wordpress installed on the blog.

My blog page:

[pmctelecom.co.uk/blog/](http://pmctelecom.co.uk/blog/)

If you right click (on chrome) > inspect element >  console it is returning 404 errors, and I think this is causing a lot of internal link issues.

I can see here: " https://www.pmctelecom.co.uk/PMC%20Telecom Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

That this is the broken link. (https://www.pmctelecom.co.uk/PMC%20Telecom)

My .htaaccess has this line:

```
RewriteRule ^PMC%20Telecom$  /  [L,R=301]  this does not seem to redirect PMC%20Telecom to /home as expected, but I have other redirects that work fine in the htaccess file.
```

Any ideas? 
I have seen somebody suggest use Wp-DBmanager, but if I put in FTP pass on any wp plug-in, it just simply dosn't take it.

Comment: Still no response as yet. Would anyone recommend speaking to my hosting company or would that be our of their remit? I have opened a ticket but no response (24 hours ago)

Comment: UPDATE: Hosting Company replied: they stated they do see 404s and that they see the following errors consistently across the site:

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
/var/www/vhosts/pmctelecom.co.uk/httpdocs/app/core/includes/functions/general.php on line 2216
[Tue Sep 01 11:39:24
2015] [warn] [client 66.249.78.147] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
/var/www/vhosts/pmctelecom.co.uk/httpdocs/app/core/includes/functions/general.php on line 2216